# support of a probability measure

Tags: measure-theory

We know that if a probability measure is not continuous ,there will be a positive measure on a single point.
must the quantity of these points be countable?

Comment: Yes, because the sum of any uncountable collection of positive numbers is infinite.

Comment: Let us hope that the number of times this was asked on the site is countable...

Comment: @T.Bongers You could say that the OP asked: is the sum of any uncountable collection of positive numbers infinite? Saying 'yes' is okay then, but not enough.

Comment: @Did. Everything 'here' (in a very broad sense) is even *finite*. The thought that even the number of drops in the ocean (with volume $\geq\epsilon>0$) is finite is a fascinating one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Define $A_{n}=\left\{ x\mid P\left(\left\{ x\right\} \right)\geq\frac{1}{n}\right\} $
for positive integers $n$.

Then $\left|A_{n}\right|\leq n$ as a
consequence of $P\left(A_{n}\right)\leq1$.

Then $A:=\left\{ x\mid P\left(\left\{ x\right\} \right)>0\right\} =\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$,
i.e. a union of finite sets.

This implies that $A$ is countable.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure and define

$$A_n := \left\{\omega \in \Omega; \mu(\{\omega\})>\frac{1}{n} \right\}.$$

Then $A_n$ is a finite set since $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$. This implies that

$$\{\omega \in \Omega; \mu(\{\omega\})>0\} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$$

is countable. In particular the claim holds if $\mu$ is a probability measure.